# OpenCart <body> tag

Tags: javascript, tags, opencart, document-body

Just quick one - I have java snippet, tag which needs to be included in my checkout page in opencart before closing `</body>` tag.

But - in checkout.tpl I can not find `</body>` tag.

Where to find this tag in OpenCartfor checkout?

Thanx

Answer (score 2):

The tag you are looking for is in the `custom/footer.tpl` file in your theme. However, that is used globally, not just on the success page. You can put the code in your checkout tpl file just fine before the

```
<?php echo $footer; ?>
```

at the bottom and it will work